# Disabling the window scale animation on Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I've recently updated Android Studio IDE to 4.0 and every time a popup window opens, it starts animating from center and performs a scale animation. I want to disable this feature, and from IDE settings I closed "Animate windows" option but the behavior did not change.

The animation I'm complaining about is this: [image: link]

Is it possible to change this behavior or is it enforced? If it's enforced I think I'll download an older version of Android Studio instead because it looks very bad to me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can disable it by appending `-Djbre.popupwindow.settype` to `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...`

Comment: What should I set it to remove this animation? I assume it should contain a value. If there is a list of values can you edit your answer please? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to set it to anything, it's only checked for presence in [the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/swing/Popup.java#L238-L242).